# Why I am not getting line in the graph?

Tags: javascript, jquery, parsing, csv, highcharts

I tried this coding but I am not getting any line in the graph, Please tell me where I am wrong.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var options = {
                chart: {
                    renderTo:'container',
                    zoomType:'xy'
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Oviedo hoy'
                },

                subtitle: {
                                text: 'datos:'
                            },

                xAxis:{
                        labels:{

                            formatter:function(){

                                return Highcharts.dateFormat('%H:%M:%S',this.value);
                            }
                  }
                },
                series: []
            };


$.get('data.csv', function(data) {
                // Split the lines

                options.series.push({
                    data:[]
                });

                var tmptimestamp = '';

                var lines = data.split('\n');
                    $.each(lines, function(lineNo, line) {
                        var items = line.split(',');
                        // header line containes categories
                        if (lineNo > 0 )
                        {


                              //parsing
                                     var datestamp = items[0].split(' '),
                                         date = datestamp[0].split('/'),
                                         time = datestamp[1].split(':'),
                                         timestamp = Date.UTC(parseFloat(date[2]),
                      parseFloat(date[1]),parseFloat(date[0]),parseFloat(time[0]),
                      parseFloat(time[1]),parseFloat(time[2]));


                                    if(tmptimestamp != timestamp)
                                    {
                                        options.series[0].data.push({
                                            x:timestamp,
                                            y:parseFloat(items[5]) 
                                        });

                                        tmptimestamp = timestamp; 
                                    }

                        }
                    });


                    var chart = new Highcharts.StockChart(options,function(chart){
                        console.log(chart);
                    });
                });
     });
```

And here is a small part of my csv, but the actual file is really long like 18,000 rows and 17 columns.

```
                Time            Tcoll   Tstor   TglyHXin
      01/01/2013 12:00:54 AM    103.34  103.32  26.94
      01/01/2013 12:01:55 AM    103.29  103.3   26.94
      01/01/2013 12:02:55 AM    103.29  103.33  26.95
      01/01/2013 12:03:55 AM    103.29  103.03  26.94
      01/01/2013 12:04:55 AM    103.34  103.27  26.94
      01/01/2013 12:05:55 AM    103.39  103.33  26.94
      01/01/2013 12:06:55 AM    103.3   103.01  26.94
      01/01/2013 12:07:55 AM    103.42  103.17  26.94
      01/01/2013 12:08:55 AM    103.37  103.16  26.94
      01/01/2013 12:09:55 AM    103.34  103.28  26.94
```

I don't know where I am going wrong, Please provide me suggestion what should I do to get the line in my graph.

Thanks in advance, looking forward for your help.

Comment: Did you try giving small amount of data ?

Comment: Do you see any error messages in the console? Can you confirm that the `.get` actually returns data and that the callback is called?

Comment: I just tried for small amount data, it work for that, but how will i make it work for big file @tracevipin

Comment: Yeah, it is showing invalid date and no line in it @MattBurland

Comment: One more thing when I tried small amount of data, it is showing wrong date @tracevipin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `turboThreshold` to higher value (see [docs](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.turboThreshold)) or change from:

```
                                    options.series[0].data.push({
                                        x:timestamp,
                                        y:parseFloat(items[5]) 
                                    });
```

to:

```
                                    options.series[0].data.push([
                                        timestamp,
                                        parseFloat(items[5]) 
                                    ]);
```

Regarding wrong date:
Months starts from 0, not from 1, so change:

```
timestamp = Date.UTC(parseFloat(date[2]),
                  parseFloat(date[1]),parseFloat(date[0]),parseFloat(time[0]),
                  parseFloat(time[1]),parseFloat(time[2]));
```

to:

```
timestamp = Date.UTC(parseFloat(date[2]),
                  parseFloat(date[1]) - 1,parseFloat(date[0]),parseFloat(time[0]),
                  parseFloat(time[1]),parseFloat(time[2]));
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Pawel Fus but it is still not working,its driving me crazy..

Comment: Is it possible to plot more than one parameter on the graph?is,yes then how? @PawelFus

Comment: Any errors from console? Regarding parameter, I don't know what do you mean.

Comment: Yes, again its not showing any line in the graph, even after making the changes, it just work for small amount of data @Pawel Fus

Comment: Regarding parameter, I mean, is this possible to have 2 or more lines in my graphs for different columns. @Pawel Fus

Comment: Have you set turboThreshold to higher than 1000? Yes, this is possible, just add more series (check Highcharts examples).

Comment: Please tell me Where to add turboThreshold? and how?? @Pawel Fus

Comment: Read my answer once again, please. Link for you: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.turboThreshold

Comment: I did set value of turboThreshold equal to 40000, but still no line in the graph @Pawel Fus

Comment: Could you show me you page? Without live example with that issue is hard to say what is wrong.

Comment: The problem is still with index, see line: `parseFloat(items[5])` - you don't have 6 elements in one line, only 4 (so max index is 3). Example: http://jsfiddle.net/s985w/1/

Comment: No, I have 10 elements on one line, the data i showed here is just a small portion of the real one @Pawel Fus

Comment: Thank a lot for your help, I really appreciate that but still not getting any line,Its driving me crazy If you can provide me your email id I can send you the actual file, if that have any problem..@Pawel Fus

Comment: I don't think that would help me. I have checked code, looks properly.  Do you have any errors in console? Couldn't you just setup a test page  with that issue and post url?

Comment: Your CSV doesn't contain '\n' (new lines) - there is only one line. So this line `$.each(lines, function(lineNo, line) {` is called only once.

Comment: so,what should I do?? @Pawel Fus

Comment: Add this '\n' after each line?

Comment: Is this the only way, there are 40000 lines, so how come it was working for a small file without any '\n' @Pawel Fus

Comment: Maybe file is generated in other way? So maybe smaller file contains that missing '\n's.

Comment: thanks, i have bugged you a lot, but still its not workin, now not even for small data @Pawel Fus

Comment: Have you added that missing '\n's?

Comment: Your data isn't in UTF-8 format, right? Try to change from '\n' to '\r'.